Wireguard DNS failure with two simultaneous peers
My desire is to establish Wireguard connections on mylaptop to network1 and network2 simultaneously.
network1 and network2 sit behind firewalls and have public domain names network1.org and network2.org per the diagram below:
network configuration and wireguard setup
From mylaptop, I am able to establish simultaneous connections to network1 and network2. As intended, I can resolve hostnames inside of network1:
ping somehost.domain1

works correctly, but I cannot resolve hostnames inside of network2:
ping somehost.domain2

I can, however, ping the IP address of hosts within network2's subnet such as: somehost.domain2:
ping 192.168.1.83

It's also worth noting that if I connect to only network1 or network2 (not both), then I can resolve hostnames as expected:
ping somehost.domain1
ping somehost.domain2

Does anyone know how to fix this setup so that I can resolve hostnames inside both network1 and network2?

It very much depends on what operating system you're running on your laptop, and whether or not it's set up to be able to resolve per-interface domains.
If your laptop is running Linux with systemd-resolved, you're better off omitting the DNS setting in your WireGuard config files, and calling resolvectl directly via PostUp scripts; like this for network1:
# network1.conf
# DNS = 192.168.144.1,domain1
PostUp = resolvectl dns %i 192.168.144.1; resolvectl domain %i ~domain1

And this for network2:
# network2.conf
# DNS = 192.168.1.254,domain2
PostUp = resolvectl dns %i 192.168.1.254; resolvectl domain %i ~domain2

